# Telling a coworker they aren't invited into my house

Tags: professionalism, management, events, off-site-events

Long story short, my former manager, but current coworker's, poor treatment resulted in me developing a case of PTSD. I was diagnosed about two months ago. However, we don't have an HR team so there is no one to disclose to or deal with her bullying behavior (the boss doesn't care as long as she is doing OK work), and leaving isn't an option right now, so I have to grin and bear working with my abuser. Luckily, she works in a different department so we only really interact during morning meetings.

I am holding a [4th of July](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(United_States)) at my house for all of my interns. Her interns are not invited since they work in a separate office from us.

My boss knows about the party, but he will not be attending. I have not told her about it, but I know she will find out about it and invite herself and her interns so she can take credit.

How do I politely tell her that she isn't allowed in my home?

Letting her in is not an option and will trigger a PTSD episode.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126217/discussion-on-question-by-user126509-telling-a-coworker-they-arent-invited-into).

Comment: Just following up: did you get any trouble from the coworker? Were any of the answers helpful?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems more suited for Interpersonal Skills

Answer (score 152):

> How do I politely tell her that she isn't allowed in my home?

Assuming she speaks to you and attempts to invite herself and/or her interns, you tell her:

> No, thank you.

No explanation needs to be given, if she persists or asks for a reason you tell her:

> My decision is final.

If they show up unannounced, you don't let them in.  It's your house, you decide who can enter.

Just be mentally prepared for her reaction due to being rejected by you.  If she was abusive in the past, she will likely be abusive after being rejected, no matter how polite you are.

Comment: That's excellent: the key takeaway seems to be: _Do not offer anything that could be used for arguing against._ If you want to avoid having to defend your side in an argument, do not offer an opportunity for one. As terse as semantically possible. "No." "You are not coming in." "Have a nice weekend. Elsewhere. Thank you." Conversation over. Door shut.

Comment: One added piece of advice, if there is a trusted colleague/friend at the party, ask them to come a bit early. That way she can't be the first to arrive and your friend can have your back if needed.

Comment: You only have enough space/logistics/resources for your own team. [Even if you lived in a castle]

Comment: @CaptainEmacs that is not relevant at all. You should never feed toxic people with anything they could argue about. They are already past the fase of rational reasoning and accepting boundaries.

Comment: Final step: If they refuse to go you can call the police.

Comment: I hope your guests don't have the habit of opening the door when it rings to help you out. Imho that's quite common at a party. Throwing her out won't be fun.

Comment: This answer would not work for me -- I would need someone else to do the confrontation. Because the idea of that confrontation alone would have already triggered a PTSD episode. I'd go with the answer by @benxyzzy.

Comment: If they show up unannounced, you might want to consider how they found out where you live... sharing confidential employee information (such as address) with other employees could warrant legal action to be taken.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Toxic people are surprisingly influential on their surroundings. If OP is sensitive to the point of PTSD, they they need a plausible perspective to not to be seen as the cause of the matter (toxic people are surprisingly good at turning around the apparent causality and it takes long time to undo).  Having a pseudo-plausible argument softens this appearance to ones surroundings.

Comment: The only reason one needs to give: *"I have the right to decide who is welcome to my house. Period."*

Comment: Perhaps adding to @skippy's comment (and maybe a little farfetched), your trusted friend/colleague could have a guests list at the door, and if she tries to pull the classic "May I speak with OP" after being denied entrance, a firm "Guests in the list, only. Have a nice day" should be enough. Once she's gone, op's friend at the door can go back to enjoy the party.

Comment: OP might want to at least once publicly state in the company that it's a party explicitly for her interns. Not to convince the other party not to come, but to make clear to other colleagues/the boss why she's getting the cold shoulder and so she cannot claim to be discriminated against by OP or the like. Otherwise imho pretty good advice.

Comment: @iBug That's an opening for “but this is a company party”. The fewer unique words, the better.

Answer (score 118):

Just clearly stipulate who the invitation is for (interns and members of X dept). It's a very common way of doing invitations anyway.

Even if someone shows her the invitation it will clearly state who is to come.

Comment: Yep. A bunch of invitations with the recipients name on them. Done.

Comment: An explicit list of names definitely (not "member of X" or "interns" - too vague.  Not a list that could be in any way reinterpreted.  If the individual mentioned is as bad as indicated they might take any vagueness as an opening.  Make it clear that it is only for explicitly named people.

Comment: Yes, "**my** party for **my** interns" is the obvious answer.

Comment: I like this answer for a number of reasons. Primarily for the approach - i.e DON'T tell her she isn't welcome. Tell those that are and ignore the rest. It's not like you're gonna tell HR, the cleaners, the accountants etc they aren't welcome. It really shouldn't be any different here. Telling her explicitly that she isn't welcome is likely to cause problems. She'll feel singled out and may well return the 'favour'.

Answer (score 79):

It's been somewhat alluded to in comments etc. already, but if you are worried about this person turning up at your house unannounced then it might really help to **have an ally**. Both at the time, and knowing that you will have one in the lead-up to your party.

You haven't stated either way, but it is probably incredibly stressful trying to contain this situation alone while you are hosting, let alone the fear hanging over you beforehand of the possibility of it. Knowing that it will not be on you alone to handle it if it happens offers literal peace of mind. If she does turn up unannounced, it will be much easier to deal with it how others have recommended, if you are not also worrying about what onlookers will think, who they will "side with" or (heaven forbid) what happens if this awful person gets out of hand.

You don't need to tell all your guests or make a big thing about it, just don't keep this wholly to yourself. If one or two trusted coworkers are aware, or even just your partner, then in that moment you will know you can project calm, firm, detached distancing without needing to engage in justification or any opening for debate. You can shut that door and people watching will know it was right. If she escalates, there will be people other than just you who are ready to help you.

She probably won't turn up at all, maybe she'd enjoy knowing that you're worrying about the possibility idk. The main reason to have this in place is rather to soothe your fears in the lead-up, by cutting down on a load of social "what ifs". What if guests think I was too rude, what if she kicks off etc. Nobody should bear those worries alone and in the event you will have a whole house of potential allies.

So just get one or two of them on side now, just in case, then when she doesn't turn up after all you won't have wasted so much emotional energy stressing about the possibility beforehand because you will know you're not, and won't be alone in handling this. These kinds of people love to get others expending emotional energy over them in that way, that's probably as far as this will go, but in the worst case having others on your side in the event will allow you to do all the detached "professional" type handling which others have recommended with your head held high.

It will probably be fine, you will have a great party, just don't carry this worry alone.

Comment: Yes, a trusted partner or family member could be your door man as well.

Comment: Yes absolutely, everyone else seems to assume that OP can perfectly control and coordinate their actions while in the middle of a PTSD episode. OP needs an ally to manage this interaction and provide the support OP needs

Comment: Having my own share of PTSD, I gotta say that this is the answer I would need.

Comment: lol. Hire a literal bouncer. If your name's not on the list, you're not coming in.

Comment: Where I live, if you were a single woman, you would have a choice of neighbours you could ask and most of them would gladly agree to help.

Answer (score 8):

***My boss knows about the party, but he will not be attending.***

Unfortunate that the boss won't be there. If this boss manages both you and the other person, and if your boss knows the gathering is happening and isn't a total asshat, it may be worth letting your boss know that you need to limit the gathering to just your own interns.

But I would DEFINITELY like to second the suggestion that you have one or more allies with you at the house BEFORE the party's announced start time, who know about the situation with your harassing colleague etc.. (I assume this person's reputation is well known, since it's hard to keep these things a secret.)

You might also consider letting the word get around that it's invitation only and size limited. Other interns may be less inclined to try to show up.

I'm so sorry you have to face this. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds like the boss _doesn't_ actually manage the situation.

Comment: `You might also consider letting the word get around that it's invitation only and size limited. Other interns may be less inclined to try to show up.` This is good advice. In fact, you have the ultimate excuse: COVID. Just let people know you're being mindful of not having too many people over.

Comment: @Möoz: I'm not sure if it's a good thing here to be polite and invent a socially acceptable excuse. The former boss was abusive to the point the OP has PTSD. Maybe it's better to be somehow confrontational.

Comment: @QuoraFeans I agree, it's best to avoid giving excuses, especially a made-up one. But that example is an option, just in case.

Answer (score 6):

Let me higlight the single key thing clearly.

*This is your own, private party, in your own house, outside working hours, with your acquaintances.* It's not some corporate event. You decide who you invite to your house. She has as much right to show up there uninvited as I do:

***None.***

If she can't handle not being invited to one's private party, that's none of your business. She is not invited. End of sentence. Set your boundaries straight, and stick to them rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

When you send out the invitations, you can include something along the lines of "I do not wish my home address to be distributed throughout the company. Please do not share this invitation with others. Those invited will be provided the address." She will likely still manage to get the address, but it will change the nature of the interaction if she shows up at your house, as she will not be able to do so without admitting to having gotten someone to share the address with her, so just by showing up she's already clearly violating your boundaries.

If she enters your property, tell her to leave. If she tries to argue, just respond "I own this property, and you are trespassing. I have no obligation to debate my actions with you. You have a legal obligation to leave."

benxyzzy has suggested that you have an ally. You will have to make the initial contact, just to establish that your ally is acting on your behalf. After that, you can leave it to your ally to tell her that she needs to leave. If she continues to refuse, calling the police and having them explain trespassing law to her is an option. If things continue to escalate, a restraining order might be something to consider.

Answer (score -2):

If the event is  off-site at your house, then it is a private event and not a public one.  You decide who gets to enter your house, not anyone else.  If someone you don't want to attend shows up, just tell them you "were not expecting" them and "didn't prepare"  for them, or  what have you and leave it at that, and ask them nicely to leave.

That is, if she invites her interns to your party.  If she herself comes, then you may have to  be a bit more forceful.  If she shows up, knowing that she is not welcome to be around you because she has bullied you, here is a simple, three-step solution to get rid of her:

1. Tell her to leave.  Nothing fancy, just a simple: "I want you to leave.  Now."  Don't be apologetic, or friendly, or make excuses.  That's all you have to say: "Leave.  Now."
2. If she  refuses to leave, you escalate immediately: "I have told you to leave.  You are now trespassing on my property.  I will give you one more chance to leave.  You will leave, now, or I will be calling the police  to have you removed by force."  Say it once, and only once.  Do not explain, do not say anything more.
3. If she still refuses to leave, call the police (911 or whatever your other local emergency number is), and do it in front of her so she is aware of what has happened.  This will elicit one of two responses: Fight, or flight.  In "fight", she will attempt to wrestle the phone out of your hand so that you can't report her to the police.  In this case, you call for help: As you are having a party, there are likely others within earshot who can come to your aid, so use them.  In most places,  fighting back in this case is considered self-defence.  Restrain her, and, if you can, hold her captive however you can while you have your call with the police, and while you await the police to arrive, so they can arrest her for trespassing and assault (the assault that occurred when she attacked you).  In "flight", she will see that you are serious and she will run, and probably say something like "that's not cool man, I didn't mean any harm, I just wanted to have a good time, don't be such a [whatever]".  Let her run.  Do not cancel your call to the police.  When the police arrive, tell them what happened, tell them all the information you have about her, tell them she is a  coworker and is abusive to you at work, etc.  The police may or may not follow up legally, but if they don't, at least you've filed a police report and you have a paper trail in case this happens again.
4. (Optional) Report this activity to her boss, that she showed up unannounced to your party that she was not invited to.  There may be work-related repercussions for this, depending on your company culture etc.

EDIT: On second thought, you should probably do step 4 anyway.  Just in case she starts sending you threatening emails at work, or makes trouble for you if you need to work together on a project, or something like that.  This should be made known to management so management knows  what type of person she is in case  other issues come up  in the future.

Comment: That was a bit of a PTSD-episode-worthy read, you know...

Comment: But necessary to know that you have to escalate all the way as needed. +1 To be clear, (1) triggers (4) for the paper trail. Randomly showing up to someone's **personal** residence is not to be tolerated.

Comment: On second thought, collapse (2) and (3): say the statement (without the words about chances and future actions) while already calling 911. The emergency line will have audio recording for evidence.

Comment: "Restrain her, and, if you can, hold her captive" it's hard to put into words how bad this advice is.  Absolutely do not do this op.

Comment: This reads like a teenage superhero story. In reality, she won't let op finish her sentence and just walk in and op will have a ptsd episode at their own party. Yay.

Comment: "As you are having a party, there are likely others within earshot who can come to your aid" - I would like to remind you about the "bystander effect", when no one intervene because everyone believe someone else will do it.

Comment: @eps to expand on your comment for those who wonder why. The motive it not to capture her, but to have witnesses of the moment and de-escalate quickly (for your own sake). You already know who the person is and therefore it is not needed to hold on, the police will find the offender anyway.

Comment: The OP is asking how to *prevent* a trauma, before a "dangerous" situation even occurs. Your answer suggests causing a direct confrontation at the party, escalating the conflict and causing the OP another trauma.

Comment: @Clockwork I'm reminded of something a first aid instructor told me many years ago. If there's an emergency, don't say "someone call an ambulance" - point at someone, make eye contact, and say "you. call an ambulance".

Comment: @DonQuiKong: and this is where the unrelated (to work)  friends come in and kick her out, without OP's presence.

Comment: @WoJ oh you mean the paid Mafia guys that kill her? Yes, that fits perfectly into the story. Next day op gets an anonymous donation from some billionaire who also hated the colleague? Sorry, but this is ridiculous.

Comment: @DonQuiKong no, of course not. I mean a friend who can take care of her and make her leave instead of OP so that this nor trigger his PTSD.

Comment: @WoJ I mean, I do get that. But if a plan is based on your friends throwing someone out of your house and that's Plan A, I really don't want to see Plan B. In my opinion, it's not a good plan.

Comment: This answer is incredibly unhelpful, as it basically gives advice on how to escalate a situation, cause conflict, and even violence - which is exactly the opposite of what OP needs. Wish I could downvote more times.

Comment: It really is hard to overstate just how bad this answer is. I am BEFUDDLED that it has a positive score. I almost never DV on Workplace. -1

Comment: *"Restrain her, and, if you can, hold her captive however you can"*. **WTF.** This is how you get a *goddam lawsuit* for assault or alike. Do you also suggest to hire some strong guy to provide physical assault? Why not go to the mafia with guns straight away? I can't put in word how terrible, bad, awful is this answer. I also can't believe this is upvoted by *anyone*, let alone at least 7 people. I believe this answer should be removed.

Comment: @Neinstein hey the mafia idea was mine. Maybe I should post it as an answer? I mean, its still a better answer than this one. +10 incoming

Comment: @DonQuiKong I mean, I'm here to learn the good advices from others! But seriously, I can't get around how 50+ people saw it's a *very* bad advice, yet only 15 decided to -1.

Comment: I can *feel* the stress, anxiety and headache which would come from following this advice by just reading this answer. This advice is terrible for someone with PTSD and looking to avoid conflict. I would have downvoted this answer had I had the reputation.

Comment: @AlexM, there, I'm glad to push it to -1 with my downvote. ;)

Answer (score -13):

I don't think she would show up. She clearly know you like her or not.

Further, if she asks, then just reject her with a random reason is also fine, no one is stupid.

Comment: "no one is stupid", you'd be surprise what kind of people are walking around in the real world.

Comment: I think this is less about stupidity and more about how far this person is willing to go to bully the OP.

Comment: Some people _are_ that stupid (see darwinawards.com). But some people will intentionally do things to hurt others, especially if one is a bully and the other person has PTSD.

Comment: Giving random reasons is absolutely wrong. You give NO reasons. NO opening for contradiction. NO invitation for discussion. You say NO. You say "NO, YOU ARE NOT COMING". You say "NO, YOU ARE NOT INVITED". You say "NO, YOU WILL BE THROWN OUT".